# Colour picker with hexadecimal notation

Tags: html, colors

I am looking for a simple colour picker tool that returns hexadecimal notation of
colour picked.
Any ideas, anyone?
Thank you.

Comment: gcolor2 is my favourite... but this doesn't belong here!

Answer (score 0):

First hit on Google:
http://jscolor.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it on my html code, was lookin for some more desktop,like an executable , found i can use common graphics tools like PS, Gimp

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice, we one: [`Color Picker`](http://www.colorpicker.com/) - First result in [`Google`](http://google.com).

Comment: Hmm color picker. thx.comes close, wish it was desktop..Figured i could use Photoshop, Gimp by the way

Answer (score 0):

JPicker works well as a color picker if your using jquery on the web.
http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, [PMeter](http://www.pegtop.net/pmeter).